# NodeJS Electron (using Quasar Framework) how to prevent config files from being compiled?

Tags: electron-packager, quasar-framework

I have a couple .JSON files I would like my application to expose to users;  I'm not sure I understand how the electron-packager wants me to make these available to users. If i put them in the `static` folder, for example, they turn up in an `unpackaged` folder within the project's `dist` folder.

I am using Quasar's framework to manage the electron side of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used `fs.readFileSync` since it takes an absolute file path.  I simply assigned it a path based on the environment.  The main obstruction was webpack; I just couldn't find a way during build to mitigate require calls being compiled (aliasing didn't seem to make any difference).

Not, perhaps, the most elegant solution but sufficient for the purposes of simply reading a JSON file on launch (which is all I need it for).